# Vagrant Ansible provisioning SSH error

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I'm trying to do some Vagrant/Ansible stuff, but running into problems from the start. Here's my Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.6.66"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
  end

  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "site.yml"
  end
end
```

site.yml is simply

```
---
- name: Bring up server with MySQL, Nginx, and PHP-FPM
  hosts: all
  remote_user: root

  roles:
    - common
```

and common/tasks/main.yml is

```
---
- name: Update apt
  apt: update_cache=yes
```

When doing `vagrant up`, the output is

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu/trusty64'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: ansible-provision_default_1412793587231_72507
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2200 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2200
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Checking for host entries
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /Users/bram/Projects/Brammm/ansible-provision
==> default: Running provisioner: ansible...

PLAY [Bring up server with MySQL, Nginx, and PHP-FPM] ************************* 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
fatal: [default] => SSH encountered an unknown error during the connection. We recommend you re-run the command using -vvvv, which will enable SSH debugging output to help diagnose the issue

TASK: [common | Update apt] *************************************************** 
FATAL: no hosts matched or all hosts have already failed -- aborting


PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
           to retry, use: --limit @/Users/bram/site.retry

default                    : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0   

Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
```

If I look at .vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory, I see the following:

```
default ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2200
```

I would expect the IP there to be the same as set in the private_network? I've been staring at this for over an hour, did I do something wrong? I have a feeling the IP isn't being set properly or something. I can `ping 192.168.6.66`.

Comment: `We recommend you re-run the command using -vvvv, which will enable SSH debugging output to help diagnose the issue` did you do that?

Answer (score 5):

The problem here that your `site.yml` overrides the remote user ansible will use to root. But, you do not provide the private key for it, nor password.

So the way, I fixed it was to set `ansible_ssh_user` to "vagrant", because it is default known user, and ansible will behave the same as `vagrant ssh` if remote_user is not overriden. And set `sudo` true, because "vagrant" user is sudoer, but not su.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.6.66"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
  end

  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "site.yml"
    ansible.extra_vars = { ansible_ssh_user: 'vagrant' }
    ansible.sudo = true
    #ansible.verbose = 'vvvv'
  end
end
```

Please refer to the "WHY DOES THE ANSIBLE PROVISIONER CONNECT AS THE WRONG USER?" section [Ansible Provisioning of Vagrant Documentation](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/ansible.html)

Answer (score 0):

Vagrant will create it's own ansible inventory file (which you've seen) with the defaults of 127.0.0.1 and 2200.

You need to specify the ansible inventory file using `ansible.inventory_path`

> A very simple inventory file for use with Vagrant might look like:
>
> default ansible_ssh_host=192.168.111.222 Where the above IP address is
>   one set in your Vagrantfile:
>
> config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.111.222"

From https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/ansible.html

Answer (score 0):

I had Ansible on Vagrant 1.7 trying to connect as `root`, probably because of some separate deployment repo group vars defaults. Possible fixes:

- set [`ansible.force_remote_user = true`](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible.html) or [`ansible_ssh_user` extra/host/group vars](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible_common.html#extra_vars) appropriately
- or move to Vagrant 1.8, which forces remote user by default, as per the [changelog](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#180-december-21-2015)

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem, where it wouldn't ssh into the server for whatever reason for provisioning.

`vagrant ssh` worked fine, but `vagrant provision` would fail to ssh, due to a timeout.

I finally connected the dots and realized that this was actually because of the VPN client that my employer has us use.  Cisco AnyConnect VPN client does some kind of buggery and makes it so that I have to restart my entire workstation to be able to run it.

Luckily, I don't have to be connected to a VPN for many things, so this only happens sporadically for me.